# Go to First Sheet Not Hidden

Tags: excel, vba

Working on a macro that will go to the first sheet. I was using:

```
Sub GoToFirstSheet()

    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(1).Select

End Sub
```

However, if sheet `1` is hidden, this wont work. How can I incorporate a way to go to the first sheet that isn't hidden?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub GoToFirstSheet()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets(i).Activate
        If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit For
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted since can handle more than just worksheets.

Comment: @user3819867: then change it to `activeworkbook` ;) and also use `activeworkbook.Sheets(i).Activate`

Answer (score 7):

This should do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GoToFirstSheet()

    Dim ws As Worksheet 'declare a worksheet variable
    'loop through all the worksheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'If the sheet is not hidden
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            ws.Select 'select it
            Exit For 'exit the loop
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: `if ws.Visible=xlSheetVisible...` ?

Comment: The `.Visible` property has 3 options: `xlSheetHidden`, `xlSheetVeryHidden` and `xlSheetVisible`what is the question? Ok.... now I understood it :D well either way it works. But I had a brainfart while coding, wanted to do your way, then i saw only the very hidden and added the hidden... haha

Comment: @SJR thank you, sometimes happens... I get my thoughts mixed and fail a bit. ^^

Comment: No great shakes, it wasn't a failure, just a temporary omission...